# More non-standard ways of allocating arbitary space on stack

Tags: c++, stack, embedded, constexpr, alloca

Currently, I am using gcc, which allows the usage of a C variable length array in a C++ constexpr function (do not ask me why). This is, of course, not a standard behaviour, but results in the desired effect.

What I am searching for are more ways to emulate the desired behaviour in other compilers. As a standard fallback, I have included an option using unique_ptr, thus emulating gcc‘s behaviour on platforms that do not support constexpr and variable stack allocation.

Here is what I got so far:

```cpp
class Integer {
private:
    int i;

public:
    constexpr
    Integer(const int& _t = 10)
    : i(_t)
    { }

    constexpr int
    get(void) const {
        return i;
    }
};

#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
#define XALLOC(type, name, count) type name[count]
#else
#include <memory>
#define XALLOC(type, name, count) std::unique_ptr<type[]> __##name(new type[count]); type* name = &__##name[0]
#endif

constexpr
int t(int num) {
    XALLOC(Integer, i, num);
    return i[0].get();
}

constinit int nu = t(10);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return t(0);
}
```

Comment: To ask the obvious: why do you need this?

Comment: trying to avoid heap allocations as much as possible while remaining cross-plattform for some library that can be used in some embedded environments without heaps (but also platforms providing heaps).

Comment: `#define XALLOC(type, name, count) type name[count]` -- This will not compile successfully for g++ if the appropriate compiler flags are used, i.e. `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie of course, since that forbids any non-standard solutions, I am especially looking for non-standard solutions since the standard does not allow it

Comment: Avoiding usage of heap in at least _real time_ embedded systems is wise, but variable allocation on the stack is just a whole bunch of different problems you would also want to avoid.  Why the desire for "non-standard" solutions - it would be better to solve the problem with portable methods.  Consider https://www.etlcpp.com/

Comment: Missing the obvious **minimal reproducible sample**. You are just demanding none std behavior, without providing enough context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work in a `constexpr` function (haven't tried), but on  most *nix platforms, you can allocate an arbitrary amount of space on the stack (well, up to a point...) with `alloca`, e.g.

```
void foo ()
{
    int *my_stuff = (int *) alloca (42);
    // Do things with my_stuff, it will go away automatically when `foo` returns
}
```

C-style cast used for brevity, and the MSVC equivalent is `_alloca` (which you can solve with a simple, conditionally defined, macro).

Please note that the Windows stack is only 1MB (although there's a linker flag to increase it), so mind how you go.  Linux and others are 8MB, but again, there's probably a way to tweak it (and, in 64 bit builds, there's no real reason not to).

VLAs are non-standard and a little bit evil, do not use them.

---

An early Christmas present for @Red.Wave, this time not a poisoned chalice (sorry about that):

````
template <class T> class StackAllocWrapper
{
public:
    StackAllocWrapper (int n, T *data) : n (n), data (data) { }
    // ... access methods ...

private:
    int n = 0;
    T *data = nullptr;
};

#define ALLOCA_SANITISER(T, n) StackAllocWrapper <T> (n, (T *) alloca (n))

void foo ()
{
    auto w = ALLOCA_SANITISER (int, 42);
    // Do things with w, the allocation will go away automatically when `foo` returns
    (void) w;
}```
````

Comment: thanks. But even GCC forbids this (weirdly enough). MSVC also does not accept it. I find it hard to understand that the language that would profit most from stack allocations (C++) make it so difficult. And another thanks for pointing out the size limit

Comment: Do you mean in a `constexpr` function?  Could well be, yes, but it should work otherwise.  If not, please tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: in a constexpr function. GCC allows constexpr VLAs but forbids constexpr alloca

Comment: Ok, that's a shame (but understandable). Why does it have to be `constexpr`?  Perhaps we can help with that.

Comment: Same problem as VLA. Not std for same reasons and caveats.

Comment: @Red.Wave Kinda.  `alloca` is available on platforms likely to be of interest to the OP, whereas MSVC will barf on a VLA (but I don't know if the OP cares about that, he doesn't say).  But you're right, non-standard.  Also, from memory, if you make the mistake of adding an initialiser a VLA will go all weird on you.  Hence 'a little bit evil'.

Comment: @PaulSanders the real problem is that you can't store and abstract away the size and beginning address in a single line. With both of these constructs, you always have a high risk of out of bounds indexing.

Comment: @Red.Wave Added a suggestion to my answer, go crazy with it.  A VLA wouldn't hack it, I think.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you for UB. Once the constructor returns, your array is destructed. Now you have a dangling pointer wrapped in that class. Any access after this point is **use-after-free**. If stack corruption get severe enough, you can observe all sort of wierd behavior.

Comment: @Red.Wave Any time.  Sorry about that, brain fart, thanks for pulling me up on it.  Fixed now (needs a macro, yeah?), checked the code generated on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oqfh6c545).  The example there is still UB ofc, but good enough for a quick check that the allocation doesn't go away before `foo` returns.

Comment: @PaulSanders needing a macro shows the underlying problem. Now you have to take care of macro related caveats. It's hard to outsmart Stroustrup. He has already discussed and discarded `alloca` and VLA: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.stroustrup.com/examples_short.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjw9aHnxZaDAxWCJBAIHZHvDlAQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1p78b1YXNU3Umvpq5NfJmj

Comment: @Red.Wave Sure, needs some brackets.  Exercise for the reader.  I think we're done with this now.

Comment: @Red.Wave Heh, seems I'm not the only one.  Nothing new in this world: https://web.archive.org/web/20141012042202/http://tlzprgmr.wordpress.com:80/2008/04/02/c-how-to-create-variable-length-arrays-on-the-stack/ Have a great Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different behaviour during constant evaluation with `if consteval`. For example, you can use `new`/`unique_ptr` during constant evaluation and a VLA/`alloca` during non-constant evaluation.

```cpp
constexpr
int t(int num) {
    if consteval {  // (If not C++23, change to `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())`)
        std::unique_ptr<Integer[]> i = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<Integer[]>(num);
        return i[0].get();
    } else {
        __extension__ Integer i[num];
        // To avoid duplication, if the body of the function was longer
        // you could extract it to a lambda or a second function that takes a pointer
        return i[0].get();
    }
}
```

And you say in your comments that this is for a library, you might be able to make it so that the user of your library allocates the memory (which they could allocate as they wish based on their constraints and use case):

```cpp
constexpr int t(std::span<Integer> i) {
    int num = i.size();

    return i[0].get();
}

// Possible uses:
static Integer large_array[MAX_SIZE];
t(std::span(large_array).subspan(0, num));

Integer vla[num];
t(std::span(vla+0, vla+num));

t(std::span(std::make_unique<Integer[]>(num).get(), num));
```

Here's a class that takes care of conditionally `delete`-ing during constant evaluation (and a macro that conditionally `new`s or `alloca`s):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <new>

template<typename T>
struct alloca_ptr {
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>, "Destructor will not be called when not in a constant evaluation");

    // Moving a stack allocation is probably a bug
    constexpr alloca_ptr(alloca_ptr&&) = delete;
    alloca_ptr& operator=(alloca_ptr&&) = delete;

    struct use_XALLOC_macro {  // (An internal type prevents accidentally constructing this type without the macro)
        T* ptr;
        constexpr explicit use_XALLOC_macro(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
        use_XALLOC_macro(const use_XALLOC_macro&) = delete;
    };

    [[nodiscard]] explicit constexpr alloca_ptr(use_XALLOC_macro allocation) noexcept : ptr(allocation.ptr) {}

    using element_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    constexpr pointer get() const noexcept { return ptr; }
    constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return ptr != nullptr; }
    constexpr element_type& operator[](std::size_t index) const noexcept { return ptr[index]; }

    constexpr ~alloca_ptr() {
        if consteval {
            ::delete[] ptr;
        }
    }

private:
    T* ptr;
};

// Unfortunately, `count` is evaluated twice so make sure it has no side effects
#define XALLOC(type, count) \
    alloca_ptr<type>(alloca_ptr<type>::use_XALLOC_macro( \
        std::is_constant_evaluated() ? ::new std::type_identity_t<type>[count] : \
        ::new ( \
            alignof(type) <= __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__ ? \
            __builtin_alloca(sizeof(type) * static_cast<std::size_t>(count)) : \
            __builtin_alloca_with_align(sizeof(type) * static_cast<std::size_t>(count), std::max(std::size_t{__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__}, alignof(type))) \
        ) std::type_identity_t<type>[count]))
```

```cpp
constexpr
int t(int num) {
    auto i = XALLOC(Integer, num);
    return i[0].get();
}
```

This works on clang and GCC at least. You can extend this to compilers that do not have `__builtin_alloca` by checking `__has_builtin(__builtin_alloca)` and changing `XALLOC` to result in a `unique_ptr<T[]>` always, or replacing it with that compiler's spelling of `alloca`.

Note that `alloca` has a slightly different scope than a VLA. You don't want to use it in a loop, since while a VLA would die and be reused, the alloca isn't freed until the current stack frame is popped (when the function it is created in returns)